# random.randomint with variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide

Ok so I am making a python random number generator with the parameters defined by the user. I am writing this on python 3.4. this is the code:

```
import random
import time
name = input("whats your name? ")
numOfNums = input("ok " + name + " how many numbers do you want to randomize? ")

def randomGenerator():
    randomFinal = random.randint(1, numOfNums)
    print (randomFinal)
    rerun = input("Do you want to pick another random number? ")
    if rerun == "yes":
        time.sleep(0.05)
        randomGenerator()
    else:
        print("you may now close this windows")

randomGenerator()
```

I am having an issue with the line:

```
randomFinal = random.randint(1, numOfNums)
```

I cannot use the variable 'numOfNums' as a parameter. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: This post is different to the other post as I did not directly ask how to convert variables into integers, others trying to do the same thing may need to see this

Comment: There are literally hundreds of existing questions where people ask why their code isn't working and the answer is because they (for no reason I can ever figure out) assume that Python will convert their input to numbers. Yours neither gives a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) nor the actual traceback (which is what most people with a similar problem would be searching for - indeed, had you *bothered to search on that error message*, you wouldn't have needed to ask), and therefore has absolutely no value to the community. **Just delete it.**

Comment: @MrGuy797 You might not have asked about changing your variable to an `int` but that's your problem. A problem that has been solved on here on SO probably dozens of times a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it an integer with `int()`:

```
import random
import time
name = input("whats your name? ")
numOfNums = int(input("ok " + name + " how many numbers do you want to randomize? "))

def randomGenerator():
    randomFinal = random.randint(1, numOfNums)
    print (randomFinal)
    rerun = input("Do you want to pick another random number? ")
    if rerun == "yes":
        time.sleep(0.05)
        randomGenerator()
    else:
        print("you may now close this windows")

randomGenerator()
```

Comment: Oh wow I forgot I can do that, thank you!